# Snowflake taskflow failed halfway

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scheduled-tasks

Say if I have a taskflow scheduled with 100 DAGs in snowflake. If the taskflow failed on the 4th task, would I be able to restart the taskflow from 4th till 100th tasks? There is a manual trigger function with EXECUTE TASK, but I am not sure if that can EXECUTE the entire taskflow? Or would that mean I will have to execute the tasks from 4th till 100th manually?

Answer (score 0):

I figured. Query the SYSTEM$TASK_DEPENDENTS_ENABLE function in Snowflake to resume.